# Setup Created in Visual Studio 2008 Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation, desktop, windows-2000

I have a problem which is that I have a desktop application that is running fine in Visual Studio 2008, I create a setup project and I'm sure that I did it in a correct way exactly like the steps [here](http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html).

After I get the setup project it says it installed successfully however when I double click on the desktop shortcut nothing happens.
Please note that I'm using .NET 2.0 and Windows 2000, I also have another version of this application that is using .NET 3.5 and it works fine on Windows 7 and any other Windows version that is compatible with .Net 3.5.
Any idea as to what is happening?

Comment: I thought people continuing to work on XP systems were crazy given that it's falling out of support in less than 6 months. But 2000?

Comment: Well, what does the event log say? Is the application actually being copied to the desired installation location? What happens if you try to run it directly from the installation folder? What happens if you simply copy all the required files to the destination system and try to run that? Have you tried anything to find the cause of the problem yourself??

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever , will this is the case I have !

Comment: Thorsten Dittmar , I try to run it from the installation folder but it's same nothing works
I'm trying to solve it since 2 weeks ! I have no idea what is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had something similar before.
In my case it was because of a missing dependency.

Take a look at the eventviewer. Maybe you can also find some
details there.